# how to bold text inside a Browser.msgBox under Google Apps script

Tags: google-apps-script

I have the following Google script linked to a sheet:

```
function onOpen() {
  var text_aux = 'texto'.bold();
  Browser.msgBox("AVISOS:\\n" + "\\n1. Prazo" + " impreterível " +     text_aux + " para preenchimento: 02/07/2017 (domingo).")
}
```

My intention is that it should show the string 'texto' in bold, when the alert box pops up. However it just shows the string within the html bold tags instead:

```
<b>texto</b>
```

not **texto**, as I want. How do I achieve it?

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
function texto()
{
  var s="AVISOS:<br />" + "<br />1. Prazo" + " impreterível " + '<strong>texto</strong>' + " para preenchimento: 02/07/2017 (domingo)."
  s+='<br /><input type="button" value="Exit" onClick="google.script.host.close();" />'
  var html=HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(s)
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(html, 'Message Title');
}
```

Comment: Sorry Cooper: I am noobie with google scripts... How exactly do I use your function texto within my spreadsheet? I just appended it after my onOpen function, but then nothing happened, after saving and launching my sheet again, except for the former message box, without the bold text...

Comment: I may have presumed something I shouldn't but I presumed that it was okay to that it was okay to contain it in a spreadsheet.  So with that said.  Open up a spreadsheet file.  Go to tools menu and select script editor. In the default code.gs file you can copy the function into the script file code.gs.  And you can execute it from there.  Or if your in another dialog or a web app you can execute it by using google.script.run.texto().