# How can I display bold text in an alert box?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to display some text to the user after they click a button in Google Sheets. I would like some of the text to be bold. I'm using `SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(text)`

I tried wrapping the text with "<b>" and "</b>" but that doesn't get applied, and just shows up in the alert box as is.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18508591/14608750) question which says that Javascript's alert box can't display bolded text. Does that also apply to the Apps Script alert box? One answer suggested JQuery Dialog box, is that an option in Apps Script for Google Sheets?

Comment: To display a JQuery Dialog you would have to use [HTML Service Custom Dialog](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/#index.html)

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44704441/14608750) question and answer are related. I might close my question, since its halfway answered by that.